# QGIS georeferencer - user profile problem

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

When running the georeferencer I sometimes find that the progress indicator hangs after a few seconds with a non-responsive message following which the program becomes unresponsive and QGIS needs to be closed. After this happens my work around is to create a new user profile, after which the georeferencer is okay again for a while, but after a day or two does the same thing again, needing yet another new user profile to get it working again. This started happening to me sometime after QGIS 3.16 and has been happening on all versions since then.
Could there be something in the user profile causing a problem?

Comment: Any plugins installed? If the problem appears again, try deinstalling all plugins to see if that solves the problem. If so, reinstall all plugins one by one and see where the problem appears.